# Why would my CocoaPods-infused Xcode build never complete, citing "Canceled" rather than "Failed" or "Success"?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, build-process, cancellation, build-script

[image: The Xcode status readout, showing '[censored] for iOS | Build Intune: **Canceled** | Today at 12:57']

I'm getting the above message every time I try to build, no matter how (Pressing the ▶ button, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, Product ❯ Run, Product ❯ Build For ❯ Running), it seems to otherwise succeed, but instead it says "Canceled". It never runs (even ⌘⌃R won't run it - I get a dialog that says "The file “[censored].app” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission …").

I suspect this is related to me trying to introduce these into the project:

- CocoaPods
- A pre-build script which installs/updates the pods

In the build log, everything succeeds (with some minor code-level warnings like deprecations), and then there's this:

[image: The last message in a build log: a warning reading 'Build stopped 2020-05-14, 14:35 9.1 seconds']

I looked to see if my script was doing anything weird, but as far as I can tell, it does everything it's supposed to and then exist with code `0`.

**I did make sure that I am not manually canceling it.** I'm not placing the cursor near the ◽️ button, I'm not pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, nothing. I even pressed run and stepped back from the machine - it still does this.

I restarted Xcode, I cleared DerivedData, I ran `pod deintegrate; pod install; pod update`, I even installed OS updates and restarted the machine. It still does this.

---

## Update

I commented out all the lines of the build script and the build succeeded. After that, I slowly reintroduced them until I found that these lines are the culprits:

```
pod install
pod update
```

If I comment out both, it builds. If I leave either or both, it Cancels. I've confirmed that both return a status code of `0`. I don't know what side-effect of these causes Xcode to Cancel the build nor how to stop it, but I know it's in there.

Comment: Consider removing and/or binary searching the lines in the `Run Script` to narrow.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @PaulBeusterien! I did just that and tracked it down. I've updated my question